# python wont write even when I use f.close

Tags: python, file, io

I'm trying to write some code that outputs some text to a list. output is a variable that is a string which is the name of the file to be written. However whenever I look at the file nothing is written.

```
with open(output, 'w') as f:
        f.write("Negative numbers mean the empty space was moved to the left     and positive numbers means it was moved to the right" + '\n')
        if A == True:
           the_h = node.h
        elif A== False:
           the_h = 0
        f.write("Start  " + str(node.cargo) + "  " + str(node.f) +"  "     +str(the_h)+"  " + '\n')
        if flag == 0:
            flag = len(final_solution)
        for i in range (1,flag):
            node = final_solution[i]
            f.write(str(node.e_point - node.parent.e_point) + str(node.cargo) + "  " + str(node.f) +'\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Could you share your whole code?

Comment: Your with statement closed the file on scope exit anyway.

Comment: The code itself is rather long. I might be able to upload a zip file somewhere if that will do?

Comment: Just par it down to the minimum example that shows the problem.  In the process you may well discover what's wrong.

Comment: After commenting out the f.close() statement it still doesn't write.

Comment: What @CodieCodeMonkey means is that you can remove the `f.close()` as it is covered with your `with`. Meanwhile, have you tried to reduce the logic and just get the write to work? So, comment out all of your conditional logic and simply `f.write("Something" + str(node.cargo))` and prove that you can do the simple write. Then build up from there.

Comment: I'm still getting nothing.

Comment: What is "output"?  Is it the name of a file?  Have you checked for exceptions raised by the open() call?  Does the file get created (even if zero length) when you run the program?

Comment: I ran through the code with pdb and found that an exception was being thrown where I wasn't expecting it. Thank you guys for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Program looks ok, check if the output is set ok, I set as a dummy filename, it worked, presuming code within the block after open has no compiler/interpreter error. The output file should be in the same directory where the source is.

```
output = "aa.txt"
with open(output, 'w') as f:
        f.write("Negative numbers mean the empty space was moved to the left     and positive numbers means it was moved to the right" + '\n')
        if A == True:
           the_h = node.h
        elif A== False:
           the_h = 0
        f.write("Start  " + str(node.cargo) + "  " + str(node.f) +"  "     +str(the_h)+"  " + '\n')
        if flag == 0:
            flag = len(final_solution)
        for i in range (1,flag):
            node = final_solution[i]
            f.write(str(node.e_point - node.parent.e_point) + str(node.cargo) + "  " + str(node.f) +'\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not add `f.close()`, as the `with` statement will do it for you. Also ensure you don't reopen the file elsewhere with `open(output, 'w')` as that will erase the file.

Comment: Sean didn't say what the exact issue was, although I'm wondering if it was related to the value stored in `output`